# Apache authentication via sql in fedora/rhel/almalinux/rocky linux

Tags: redhat, fedora, rocky-linux, rhel9

on fedora I installed apache and mysql, I created the user with certain privileges and I populated the database, but I can't connect apache with sql. Can anyone help me on how to do it?
I've tried editing my httpd.conf file but nothing, I would expect when I put my ip address on the browser it looks for my credentials, I enter my database credentials and access the page

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what you are trying to achieve, what your expections are here nor what you have already tried.

Apache can only do HTTP authentication (basic and digest) which is very limited / basic. It is convenient as a quick hack to keep people out of your website - but no more than that. As a quick hack solution, there doesn't seem to be a justifcation for using a database (requires additional modules) rather than just s simple .htpasswd file.

You DID NOT say

- if you were trying to implement HTTP authentication or something more appropriate
- how you created the user
- how you changed the httpd.conf file
- what happenned after you made these changes (browser behaviour, log entries)

Comment: You're right, so I should set up an apache server and every time I type my ip address from my browser I should authenticate with the sql user credentials. For sql I simply made a db and inside a table with two users. I modified my httpd.conf file following the apache doc exactly like this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html. However, when I go to put the credentials in my browser I get a 501 error

Comment: Check your logs

Comment: My logs are:
[Mon Jun 12 15:55:09.062579 2023] [dbd:error] [pid 22000:tid 22000] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): AH00629: Can't connect to mysql: Can't connect to server on '192.168.228.128' (13)
[Mon Jun 12 15:55:09.062666 2023] [dbd:error] [pid 22000:tid 22000] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): AH00633: failed to initialise
[Mon Jun 12 15:55:09.062670 2023] [dbd:crit] [pid 22000:tid 22000] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): AH00636: child init failed!